# Why can I see through the objects in Solid mode?

Tags: 3d-view

Tried changing the clip start and clip end, tried tweaking some values in viewport display under *Object Properties* tab, tried to find out where the hell this *Limit selection to visible* is (sadly not available in Blender 2.9+).

Does someone knows how to solve this issue?

*Edit Mode* - Side view screenshot for better understanding how the overall mesh really looks:
[image: Edit Mode - Side view for better understanding]

*Edit Mode* - Front view with solid mode ON but *X-Ray* mode OFF, chair's Back Leg visible through the mesh :
[image: Edit Mode - Front view with solid mode ON and X-Ray mode OFF, chair's Back Leg visible through the mesh]

Same as previous image with *X-Ray* mode ON :
[image: Same as previous image with X-Ray mode ON]

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. "Limit Selection to Visible" was available in _Edit Mode_, you're in _Object Mode_ at the moment. In newer versions of Blender this feature is replaced by "Toggle X-Ray Mode" which works in _Edit Mode_ more or less like the old feature. In _Object Mode_ it makes the meshes semi-transparent, but in your screenshot the _X-Ray Mode_ is not enabled and the objects are not transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have enabled *Viewport Display* > *In Front* in the *Object Settings* of the chair object.

[image: in_front]

Answer (score 1):

[image]I searched for this issue because I had a similar problem where I couldnt see through  in object mode, with solid shading and xray on. I hope it helps someone.

[image]

then

Comment: The OP explicitly stated and showed on screenshots the x-ray is off. Still, to a visitor from google, this answer could be helpful.